# How can I retrieve Title+Description from YouTube

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have this javascript code :

```
function showMyVideos(data) {
    var feed = data.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];

    if (entries.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            swfobject.embedSWF(entries[i].media$group.media$content[0].url + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&autoplay=' + (false ? 1 : 0), 'ytplayer_' + i, '330', '290', '9.0.0', false, false, { allowfullscreen: 'true' });
        }
    }
}
```

that retrieve the youtube embeds from a YouTube channels by this call :           http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/UserChannel/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&orderby=published&callback=showMyVideos.

What I'd like to get is also title and description for each video (maybe storing them in an array, into the for cycle).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html